# Request Windows Vista UAC elevation if path is protected?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-vista, uac, elevated-privileges

For my C# app, I don't want to always prompt for elevation on application start, but if they choose an output path that is UAC protected then I need to request elevation.

So, how do I check if a path is UAC protected and then how do I request elevation mid-execution?

Comment: [Getting Elevated Privileges on Demand using C# (Codeproject)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105506/Getting-Elevated-Privileges-on-Demand-using-C)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The best way to detect if they are unable to perform an action is to attempt it and catch the `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

However as @[DannySmurf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941/dannysmurf) [correctly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533/request-vista-uac-elevation-if-path-is-protected#17544) you can only elevate a COM object or separate process.

There is a demonstration application within the Windows SDK Cross Technology Samples called [UAC Demo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970890.aspx).  This demonstration application shows a method of executing actions with an elevated process.  It also demonstrates how to find out if a user is currently an administrator.

Comment: Nice reference to UAC demo, exactly what I needed. Thanks very much. Wish I could give more rep sometimes!

Comment: @Ryan You're welcome.  I'm a little frustrated how hard UAC seems to be in a managed environment. Feel free to browse my user profile and upvote my other questions! :)

Comment: BTW, the exception name is UnauthorizedAccessException with z in Unauthorized. Just that ;)

Answer (score 17):

Requesting elevation mid-execution requires that you either:

1. Use a COM control that's elevated, which will put up a prompt
2. Start a second process that is elevated from the start.

In .NET, there is currently no way to elevate a running process; you have to do one of the hackery things above, but all that does is give the user the appearance that the current process is being elevated.

The only way I can think of to check if a path is UAC elevated is to try to do some trivial write to it while you're in an un-elevated state, catch the exception, elevate and try again.

Comment: Note that this is not a .NET limitation -- it's a general limitation of the User Account Control system.

Comment: Note that is not a UAC limitation -- it's a general limitation of the security model in Windows NT (a running process cannot change its security token).

Comment: Note that it is a good thing - otherwise malicious attacker could inject code into pre-elevation process, and this code would be elevated together with this process.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it is of any help for you but you can take a look at this blog post:

http://haishibai.blogspot.com/2010/01/tiy-try-out-windows-7-uac-using-c-part_26.html

Answer (score 1):

You may want to notify the user that the path is protected and ask them to output the file to a "safer" area.  This way your app will not need elevation.  I'm sure it depends on your users and what you are trying to do, however I don't think it's too much to kindly let the user know you don't feel ok dumping xyz into the Windows/System32 folder.

Answer (score -1):

If your secondary drive has it's own file permissions, like say you have an other copy of windows installed on it. It will prompt.

It will also prompt if files are in use, which sometimes occurs if you have windows explorer open to the same directory and the file selected with a file previewer displaying the contents... there are some other oddities, but generally you get asked for file permission if the file is in use or it's a sensitive directory.

If you do loop the FolderBrowserDialog , make sure to notify the user why, so they dont get mad at your app.

Note: it does stink there is no .net way of asking for permission, maybe p/invoke the win32 api...?

Comment: P/Invoking wouldn't change anything; the rules for UAC are the same whether you're managed or native. It's COM, external process, or bust.

Answer (score -1):

UAC can elevate object based on their GUID, this would (In theory) mean that any class with a GUID can be elevated, The UACDemo should also show how to do this