# library for self updating WPF app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, installation

Looking for an existing library to self update a wpf prism app silently, the plugins are easily updated but the main .exe typically installed in ~program files~ requires elevated permissions which can be addressed by launching a updater .exe with higher permissions

Found some very old questions similar to this

- [Auto-update library for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691663/auto-update-library-for-net)
- [Self-Updating .NET client application which needs to write in the Program File folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524875/self-updating-net-client-application-which-needs-to-write-in-the-program-file-f)
- [How to elevate privileges only when required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573086/how-to-elevate-privileges-only-when-required)

Hoping there's some package which takes care of the little details before rolling out my own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Shimmer](https://github.com/github/shimmer) provides an Auto-Update mechanism.

Other options:

- [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx)
- [NAppUpdate](https://github.com/synhershko/NAppUpdate)
- [AutoUpdaterDotNet](http://autoupdaterdotnet.codeplex.com/)