# Request permission to write to Program Files directory during run time

Tags: c#, permissions, windows-vista

I'm in a position right now where my program *needs* access to write to the Program Files directory. From what I can tell, it seems like applications can request this kind of permission while they're running (the screen will go dark, and a box will pop up with Continue and Cancel buttons), although I'm not sure what I have to do to cause this to pop up.

If anyone can help, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked and answered several times.

The short answer is, you can only do it through COM or launching another process.

See this question: [Request Windows Vista UAC elevation if path is protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533/request-windows-vista-uac-elevation-if-path-is-protected)

Comment: Thank you for that information, although it looks like in my case, the easiest method would be to have the program start with elevated access in the beginning with the manifest file. This will most likely be very valuable information for other people though!