# elevate privileges in C# , Access to the path 'c:\Documents and Settings' is denied

Tags: c#, privileges

When I try to access files on my desktop or in some other places from my c# app, it throws an error **"Access to the path 'c:\Documents and Settings' is denied."**.

If I understand right, it is because my app doesn't have privileges to access certain directories?

What can I do to elevate such privileges ?

Thanks!

Comment: If you mean as a user and not as a program, you might want to check out http://superuser.com

Comment: @harpo: I assume he means as a program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Request Windows Vista UAC elevation if path is protected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533/request-windows-vista-uac-elevation-if-path-is-protected)

Answer (score 2):

See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533/request-windows-vista-uac-elevation-if-path-is-protected)