# how can i replace a file asking for elevation

Tags: c#, winforms, uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Request Windows Vista UAC elevation if path is protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533/request-windows-vista-uac-elevation-if-path-is-protected)

Hi all, i need to overwrite some specific file in c:\program files...., for UAC i don't have writing permissions to that file, and here is my question how can i ask for elevation to overwrite that file?
The code is written in c# and is a Windows Forms app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start another process with elevated permissions, using the `runas` verb when starting the process.

Something like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("pathtoyourexecutable.exe");
info.Verb = "runas";
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = info;
process.Start();
```

I don't think there is any way to get out of needing to create a new process, it can't be done at the Thread level. You could use Out-of-Process COM objects, but that's even more trouble.

Comment: thanks i add another project to my solution that do the elevated things and from the non elevated i add your code to launch the resulting exe of the first project . It works exactly as i need.